# How to get a subset of a collection to calculate min, max and average of certain values in a collection

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, collections

I have a collection in C# like this:

```
Collection<double> temp = new Collection<double>();
```

and **I need to calculate the maximum, minimum and average value in the collection from a certain index to the end of the collection. For example, from the 10th item to the last item in the collection.**

I use `temp.Max();`, `temp.Min();` and `temp.Average();` to calculate those values in the entire collection but I don't know how to do that for certain values in the collection.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: So your question is not _"How to calculate ..."_, but _"How to get a subset of a collection"_, which is answered in [Enumerate through a subset of a Collection in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884732/enumerate-through-a-subset-of-a-collection-in-c).

Comment: @CodeCaster: Or you could look at it as the question being "how to calculate" and the answer being "by getting the subset you want to calculate over".

Comment: @Chris I disagree, OP knows how to calculate for the entire collection, so the calculation part is irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, if he knows how to get a subset he can get a solution but that assumes he knows that getting a subset is the best way to do this. There may have been the option to pass a filter into the methods being used or something. Implying that the OP should have asked a different question is suggesting levels of knowledge that he didn't necessarily have.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Of course, the only thing I need is how to get a subset of a collection, the other part I new. I change the title of the question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just `skip` the number of items and then apply the aggregation functions like below!

```
var startIndex = 10; // zero-based, say
var max = temp.Skip(startIndex).Max();
var min = temp.Skip(startIndex).Min();
var avg = temp.Skip(startIndex).Average();
```

Answer (score 3):

Say you want to calculate the average of the value from index 3 onwards

```
values.Skip(3).Average();
```

Say you want to calculate the average of the value between index 3 and 7 (inclusive)

```
values.Skip(3).Take(5).Average();
```